# How Do I Create a multi submit form with no page reload?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to create a form that has multiple questions, upon each question they can click next, but the page does not load

For example

http://www.garmin.com/us/intheair/ads-b/#scroll-to-installation-planner

Click Begin

The page does not reload, and with each radio option selected and clicking next, also does not load a new page... how do I do something like this?

Comment: You need to use Ajax. Ajax loads and refreshes specific page parts.

Comment: example/tutorial?
I get that I need to use something, but I cannot seem to find any help - all that comes up is Drupal links...

Comment: You can create form steps in tabs, with each question answered switch to new tab.

Comment: Here's a quick example, [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mdesdev/GE9Hp/).

Answer (score 1):

1. You are not mandated to place your inputs inside a *form element*, if your button is not in a form element, then it will not submit the input data.
2. If you choose to place your inputs inside a , which is fine, do NOT assign the attribute `type` of the button with the value `submit`.
3. If you choose to you `<button type="submit"></button>` or `<input type="submit" />`, which is OK, then you must intercept the click event and handle it in order to achieve custom behaviour.

Here goes:

HTML

```
<input type="submit" onclick="goNext(event)" />
```

JS

```
var goNext = function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // this stops the button from submitting the form on click

    // so then.. collect the data and put it somewhere safe for later use
    // when you are done collecting inputs, you should submit it manually, using XMLHttpRequest (a.k.a AJAX)
};
```

What is XMLHttpRequest? - You may find out for yourself [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

Answer (score 1):

After clicking next, don't reload the page.

Instead store all the selected variables in a javascript variable,

for example:

```
var results = []l
$("#next-button").click(function() {
    results.push($("select1").val());
    // push other results to results array
})
```

then at the end, you can make an ajax call to submit results:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "some.php",
    data: results
})
.done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
});
```

Let me know if you need more help

(this method is facilitated by jquery)

Comment: This would work with radio buttons as well?

Comment: Yes to check the value of a radio button use: $('radio:checked').val();