# How to keep a customer on the same page after they click "add to cart"

Tags: html

I'm attempting to create my first business webpage. I would like to add a message box where they can submit a personalized message. My question is, how can I code it so they can enter the message and submit it, but not be redirected to their shopping cart (paypal)?

This is the code as of now:

```
<!-- START SAMPLE PAYPAL FORM 5 -->

<form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" style="margin: 0px">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="website@email.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="Custom Message">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://your-domain.com/thanks-payment.htm">
    <input type="hidden" name="no_note" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="quanity" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="add" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="0.01">

<!-- START COMMENTS LINES -->
<input type="hidden" name="on0" value="Custom Message">Enter Item Comments:<br>
<TEXTAREA ROWS="4" COLS="17" name="os0">
</textarea><br>
<!-- END COMMENTS LINES -->

<input type="image" src="http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but22.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Submit Quote" vspace="4"><br>

</form>
<!-- END SAMPLE PAYPAL FORM 5 -->
```

Comment: Ajax. Your question needs more tags so we know what's available in terms of scripting.

Comment: You could also have two buttons, one which 'Add to Cart' and will submit the message and another one which 'Checkout' and redirect to paypal

Comment: Also as user isherwood said, add more tags to your post. Html is not enough in this case. Add paypal, javascript, jquery

Answer (score 0):

A simple way,

Look here for basic jQuery UI Modal Window:

http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

And here to make the ajax call to the server with jQuery:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

See this Stackoverflow question for an example:

[How Do I Create a multi submit form with no page reload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24873509/how-do-i-create-a-multi-submit-form-with-no-page-reload/24873719#24873719)